# Regex extraction of text data between 2 commas in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have a bunch of text in a dataframe (df) that usually contains three lines of an address in 1 column and my goal is to extract the district (central part of the text), eg:

```
73 Greenhill Gardens, Wandsworth, London
22 Acacia Heights, Lambeth, London
```

Fortunately for me in 95% of cases the person inputing the data has used commas to separate the text I want, which 100% of the time ends ", London" (ie comma space London). **To state things clearly therefore my goal is to extract the text BEFORE       ", London" and AFTER the preceding comma**

My desired output is:

```
Wandsworth
Lambeth
```

I can manage to extract the part before:

```
df$extraction <- sub('.*,\\s*','',address)
```

and after

```
df$extraction <- sub('.*,\\s*','',address)
```

But not the middle part that I need. Can someone please help?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

```
# target ", London" and the start of the string
# up until the first comma followed by a space,
# and replace with ""
gsub("^.+?, |, London", "", address)
#[1] "Wandsworth" "Lambeth"
```

Or

```
# target the whole string, but use a capture group 
# for the text before ", London" and after the first comma.
# replace the string with the captured group.
sub(".+, (.*), London", "\\1", address)
#[1] "Wandsworth" "Lambeth"
```

Answer (score 9):

You could save yourself the headache of a regular expression and treat the vector like a CSV, using a file reading function to extract the relevant part. We can use `read.csv()`, taking advantage of the fact that `colClasses` can be used to drop columns.

```
address <- c(
    "73 Greenhill Gardens, Wandsworth, London", 
    "22 Acacia Heights, Lambeth, London"
)

read.csv(text = address, colClasses = c("NULL", "character", "NULL"), 
    header = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)[[1L]]
# [1] "Wandsworth" "Lambeth"
```

Or we could use `fread()`.  Its `select` argument is nice and it strips white space automatically.

```
data.table::fread(paste(address, collapse = "\n"), 
    select = 2, header = FALSE)[[1L]]
# [1] "Wandsworth" "Lambeth"
```

Comment: Well this should work about 95% of the time.  The other 5% is the data provider's fault.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options that aren't dependent on the city name being the same. The first uses a regex pattern with `stringr::str_extract()`:

```
raw_address <- c(
  "73 Greenhill Gardens, Wandsworth, London", 
  "22 Acacia Heights, Lambeth, London",
  "Street, District, City"
)

df <- data.frame(raw_address, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$distict = stringr::str_extract(raw_address, '(?<=,)[^,]+(?=,)')

> df
                               raw_address     distict
1 73 Greenhill Gardens, Wandsworth, London  Wandsworth
2       22 Acacia Heights, Lambeth, London     Lambeth
3                   Street, District, City    District
```

The second uses `strsplit()` and makes getting the other elements of the address easier:

```
df$address <- sapply(strsplit(raw_address, ',\\s*'), `[`, 1) 
df$distict <- sapply(strsplit(raw_address, ',\\s*'), `[`, 2)
df$city <- sapply(strsplit(raw_address, ',\\s*'), `[`, 3)

> df
                               raw_address              address    distict   city
1 73 Greenhill Gardens, Wandsworth, London 73 Greenhill Gardens Wandsworth London
2       22 Acacia Heights, Lambeth, London    22 Acacia Heights    Lambeth London
3                   Street, District, City               Street   District   City
```

The split is done on `,\\s*` in case there is no space or are multiple spaces after a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
(?<=, )(.+?),
```

Works with any data set location doesn't have to be in london.

Comment: This does work, but it leaves a comma at the end of each string.